# Cloudflare tunneling with Postgres

Tags: java, database, postgresql, localhost, cloudflare

So i am working on mobile app using Java
It has to use Database (Postgres).
I am using cloudflare to host everything ( The server of the database on the TCP and also the PGadmin4)
The Pgadmin works good but here comes the problem:
I cannot use the server because when i host it then it will use the https protocol as url
which is a problem because in order to use it in java or anything else it has to be in the form of:
jdbc:postgresql://dbserver.urhost.com:80/postgres
and mine looks like this :
https://dbserver.urhost.com.

here is an example of the tunneling iam use:
[image]
both of them are running on a docker.
Am i missunderstanding something ?
and how can i do all of that?

I tried everything i saw and nothing worked for me sadly

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through Access first, then you will be able to start a connection to your db. I am not going to discuss how good is the idea of exposing the db to the internet....

When the CF daemon is started on the client side, you need to establish the tunnel:

```
cloudflared access tcp --hostname dbserver.urhost.com --url localhost:5432
```

This link should help: https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/applications/non-http/arbitrary-tcp/

Comment: Hi thanks so much and you said " I am not going to discuss how good is the idea of exposing the db to the internet...."
How is it normaly done?
like how do apps do that?